# Call JavaScript from within an ASP.NET MVC Partial View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have created an ASP.NET MVC partial view and I am calling it via the HTML.Action helper method:

```
@Html.Action("GetMyPartialView", "MyController", new { myParameter})
```

The partial view contains a control that needs some JavaScript to be called (a JavaScript library in an external JavaScript file).
How can I call this JavaScript code from within my partial view.

I tried using the script element inside the partial view:

```
<script>
    MyJavaScriptFunction();
</script>
```

This did not work. Probably the external JavaScript files (e.g. jQuery) have not been loaded at that time.

What is the recommended way to execute JavaScript code when a partial view has been rendered?

Comment: call the javascript inside the main view where partial view is rendering

Comment: Put in in the main view and wrap it in `document.ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had almost similar situation. What i did was added javascript in the main view. You try add javascript in the main view from where you are calling

```
 @Html.Action("GetMyPartialView", "MyController", new { myParameter})
```

Comment: You save me from spending more time with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use java script sections in partial views. They simply don't work. So keep the @section JavaScript in the main view in order to register scripts and then render the partial view

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax call to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(

    //Do ajax call  
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "controller action url",    
        data : {                          
                  //Data need to pass as parameter                       
               },           
        dataType: 'html', //dataType - html
        success:function(result)
        {
           //Create a Div around the Partial View and fill the result
           $('#partialViewContainerDiv').html(result);                 
        }
```

//Action

```
       public ActionResult GetMyPartialView(int myParameter)    
       {    
         //return partial view instead of View   
          return PartialView("YourView", resultSet);   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  You can call a javascript function in the partial view from within the partial view.  I created a hidden field and defined the onclick event to call the function I needed to call to initialize the dialog in the partial view.  Then I triggered the click event for that hidden field.

Code in partial view:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="initializeDialog" onclick="initializeDialog();" />

<script>
    function initializeDialog(){
        // Do stuff
    }
</script>
```

Code in containing view:

```
<script>
    $('#InitializeDialog').trigger('click');
</script>
```